# How to bind datagridviewcomboboxcell and adding valuemember and displaymember

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

Hiii to all,

i am developing desktop application in VB.NET as well as in C#,
i have got every concept of simple page CRUD application and right now i am developing page with master-transaction table concept and i need to bind combo box in datagridview, but i am not getting any way how to do it,

So any help regarding this topic will be appreciated,

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have DataGridViewComboBoxColumn then to bind every ComboBoxCell in this column to given data source you do it like this:

```
private void Bind(ICollection<YourObject> source)
{
     //assume col is the combobox column
     col.DisplayMember = "Name";  //name of property that will be displayed in combo box
     col.ValueMember = "Id";      
     col.DataSource = source;
}
```

And that is it :).